# swt: slectionChanged is fired upon combo box expansion

Tags: eclipse, swt, jface

This happens only on Linux. I have a ComboViewer where some elements trigger a dialog to appear. What happens (I debugged this) is when combo box is expanded ISelectionChangedListener.selectionChanged is fired. This causes first element of the viewer to be selected and dialog launched. This occurs in a two page wizard, so once this happens and I go to previous page and then come back to the one with the viewer I don't see selectionChanged firing upon combo box expansion.
On Windows I don't see this problem - selectionChanged only occurs when element is explicitly selected from the combo box.
Does anybody know if this is a known problem and is there fix for it? I understand that my case is somewhat unique.

thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a bug to me.  I understand you can search the Eclipse bug database, this might be a repeat.